# DOMXPath DOM parser with PHP: Skip a class

Tags: javascript, php, xpath, domxpath

I want to skip the first `"a" <a href="URL#" title="TITLE">TITLE</a>`

And select all others under class *posted-in*

```
$models = $xpath->query("//p[@class='posted-in']//a");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $models->length; $i++) {
        $result->add_model($models->item($i)->getAttribute('a'));
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<p class="posted-in">
            Posted in <a href="URL#" title="TITLE">TITLE</a>
on Mar 16, 2017 featuring <a href="URL#">MODEL1</a>, 
                          <a href="URL#">MODEL2</a>, 
                          <a href="URL#">MODEL2</a></p>
```

I'm using this code with tag "alt" Goodwork

```
$models = $xpath->query("//li[@class='models']//img");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $model->length; $i++) {
        $result->add_model($models->item($i)->getAttribute('alt'));
    }
```

But I'm Confused... How can I select the `a` text?

Comment: `->getAttribute('alt')` - I don't see any `alt` attribute on any of your links

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  Hi, I just said If I use `alt` result is good. 
But confuse on this line `<a href="URL#">MODEL2</a>` what should I select in `->getAttribute('alt')`. I just know "alt"

Comment: show the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `$models = $xpath->query("//li[@class='models']//img");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $models->length; $i++) {
            $result->add_model($models->item($i)->getAttribute('alt'));
        }`

HTML: models

`<li class="models"> <a href="/models/models name"> <span class="thumb"> <img class="lazy" src="models/4215.jpg" data-original="models/4215.jpg" height="134" width="113" alt="models name" style="display: block;"> </span> models name </a> </li>`

Comment: *'I want to skip the first "a"...'*. Just start your for-loop from `$i = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The text content of an element node is available in the property `DOMElement::$textContent`. This value includes any descendant text node.

If you need to ignore the first node in your result you can add a condition.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<p class="posted-in">
            Posted in <a href="URL#1" title="TITLE">TITLE</a>
on Mar 16, 2017 featuring <a href="URL#2">MODEL1</a>, 
                          <a href="URL#3">MODEL2</a>, 
                          <a href="URL#4">MODEL2</a></p>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = '//p[@class="posted-in"]/a[position() > 1]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $a) {
  var_dump($a->textContent, $a->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Output:

```
string(6) "MODEL1"
string(5) "URL#2"
string(6) "MODEL2"
string(5) "URL#3"
string(6) "MODEL2"
string(5) "URL#4"
```

Comment: Hi, @thw Thanks for help,, If I don't want to skip the first
`<div class="galleryDetails">
                    Featuring model: <a class="g_star r" href="/models/Liona">Liona</a>, <a class="g_star r" href="/models/Sheri">Sheri</a>                        &nbsp; Produced by studio: <a href="/sites/" class="g_site">sponser</a>.
            </div>`

Comment: If you don't want to skip the first link, remove the condition for it, or change it to whatever condition you need.

Comment: Hi, @ThW how I can remove the last one a text Example I want ignore a text name (+ suggest)